# TypeScript 2 + Webpack 3で、同じライブラリを通常のモジュールとしてインストールすると動くが、@typesの型定義だけをインストールするとエラーになる

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

TypeScript 2 + Webpack 3を用いて、外部ライブラリ（モジュール）を使用したアプリケーションを作ろうとしているのですが、このとき、あるライブラリAについて

- ライブラリA本体をnpm installでインストールすると正常にビルドできる
- ライブラリAの型定義のみ（@types/A）をnpm installでインストールするとビルドに失敗する

という現象が発生し、解決方法が分からずに悩んでおります。
お手数ですが、解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか。

※私の推測では、おそらく@typesの位置をWebpackに教えないといけないのかと考えていますが
　そのための適切な方法が分からない状態です。

## 環境

Typescript 2.6.1
Webpack 3.8.1
npm 5.5.1

Visual Studio Code上でソースファイルを開いた場合には、特にエラーが出ず
ライブラリ（jQuery）の入力補完も動作することを確認

## ソースファイル

### index.d.ts

```
import * as $ from "jquery";

function test(){
    return $('#TEST').text();
}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpacktest1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },
    resolve: {
        // 解決可能な拡張子に'.ts'を追加
        extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".json"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // '.ts'の全てのファイルを、'awesome-typescript-loader'で扱う
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" }
        ]
    }
};
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

## 出力

```
$ webpack --verbose

[at-loader] Using typescript@2.6.1 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from C:\work\webpacktest1/tsconfig.json.


[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...

[at-loader] Ok, 0.073 sec.
Hash: ba68d05679d08d7b9f26
Version: webpack 3.8.1
Time: 1626ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  2.79 kB       0  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = bundle.js
chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 160 bytes [entry] [rendered]
    > main [0] ./src/index.ts
    [0] ./src/index.ts 160 bytes {0} [depth 0] [built]

ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in 'C:\work\webpacktest1\src'
resolve 'jquery' in 'C:\work\webpacktest1\src'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\work\webpacktest1\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:\work\webpacktest1\package.json (relative path: ./src)
    resolve as module
      C:\work\webpacktest1\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\work\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in C:\work\webpacktest1\node_modules
        using description file: C:\work\webpacktest1\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: C:\work\webpacktest1\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: C:\work\webpacktest1\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jquery)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\work\webpacktest1\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\work\webpacktest1\node_modules\jquery.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\work\webpacktest1\node_modules\jquery.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\work\webpacktest1\node_modules\jquery.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              C:\work\webpacktest1\node_modules\jquery doesn't exist
[C:\work\webpacktest1\src\node_modules]
[C:\work\node_modules]
[C:\node_modules]
[C:\work\webpacktest1\node_modules\jquery]
[C:\work\webpacktest1\node_modules\jquery.ts]
[C:\work\webpacktest1\node_modules\jquery.js]
[C:\work\webpacktest1\node_modules\jquery.json]
[C:\work\webpacktest1\node_modules\jquery]
 @ ./src/index.ts 3:8-25
```

Answer (score 1):

すみません、自己解決してしまったかもしれません。

webpack.config.jsの中に、**externals** を追加することで、正常に動作するらしいことに気が付きました。（今回であれば外部ライブラリとしてjQueryを使うため、externalsにjQueryを追加）
お騒がせしました。

## webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    // (中略)

    externals: {
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    },
};
```

もしも、これが正しい解決方法でないというご意見などありましたら、追加のコメントや回答などを頂けると助かります。